# UPDATE price (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I need a query for MySQL...

I need change the price divided by 2 .. something like

Table name "Armor"

```
ID  NAME  PRICE
----------------
1   Armor  200
```

...and query should divide the price by 2.. Like the following (which doesn't work):

```
UPDATE `armor` 
   SET `PRICE` = 'PRICE/2'
```

Comment: be careful with queries like this - you'll update all your records in your database.  you might want to get in the habit of using a `WHERE` clause with `UPDATE` statements.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the quotes: `UPDATE armor SET PRICE=PRICE/2`

Comment: The gotcha here is in `'PRICE'='PRICE/2'`, you are trying to set `PRICE` to the string `"PRICE/2"` and it doesn't like that as `PRICE` is an integer field.